# Palm rejection issue with Blender on HP zbook x2

Tags: windows, installation

I'm having issues with the palm rejection in Blender on the HP zbook x2. It uses HP's custom wacom driver. When the pen is close to the screen it should ignore any touch, but it seems to be picking up touch too. So the cursor doesn't know where to go and starts flickering. Attach is a video I put on youtube about the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPu4HqwrRjU&t=188s

I've been in contact with HP support and since Blender is a 3rd party app, they won't do anything unless I get a case number from Blender developers and then submit the case number to HP. I'm at a lost as to who to contact on Blender.org. I'm hoping someone on here has a fix for this issue or can direct me to someone on Blender.org who can help. Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and it was in plain sight...

1. Open your HP Create Control Panel
2. Edit the Function buttons and select the dropdown for any of them
3. Choose "Touch On/Off"
   [image]

Pressing your newly configured button will disable touch, so you can draw with the pen and not be disturbed by resting your palm on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Test it by holding the pen in your left hand, touch the screen with your pen and try to draw with your right hand index finger.

I was suspicious of my zBook's palm reject ability as well, but it's because when the pen goes out of range (which is very short) it enables touch again and while my palm is on the screen it causes issues. Drawing naturally is difficult because of this, but if I focus and keep the pen very close to the screen within range I don't have any issues.

I've tried to disable touch altogether while leaving pen touch enabled, which is exactly how Windows 10 Sketchbook behaves, but I haven't figured it out yet. That would be the ideal solution to have a "pen only" mode.